# File processing: Combining multiple files with different number of columns and rows

Tags: bash, shell, file

I have multiple tab delimieted files where only the two first columns are in common. I'm trying to combine them in one tab delimited file .

Example: let's say we have 3 files (file1, file2, file3) that we want to combine into file4.

(row and column names  are just for demonstration purposes and are not included in any of the files)

Input files =>

File1: 2 rows(r1,r2), 3 columns(c1,c2,c3)

```
    c1 c2 c3

r1  a  b  c 

r2  d  e  f
```

File2: 3 rows(r3,r4,r5), 3 columns(c1,c2,c4)

```
    c1 c2 c4 

r3  1  2  3 

r4  4  5  6 

r5  7  8  9
```

File3: 1 row(r6), 4 columns(c1, c2, c5, c6)

```
    c1 c2 c5 c6 

r6  w  x  y  z
```

Output file =>

for all  3 files, the 2 first columns (c1, c2) have the same name

File4:

```
    c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 

r1  a   b  c  -  -  - 

r2  d   e  f  -  -  - 

r3  1   2  -  3  -  - 

r4  4   5  -  6  -  - 

r5  7   8  -  9  -  - 

r6  w   x  -  -  y  z
```

What I'm trying  to do is: for each of the files add the needed empty columns so that all files have the same number of columns then reorder the columns with "awk" then use "cat" to stack them vertically. But I don't know if this is the best way or there is a more efficient way to do it.

Thanks,

Comment: Rephrase your query.

Comment: I hope this edited version make more sense

Comment: If the files do not have the column names, how does the proposed script infer them? eg., how does it know that the third column in File1 is c3 but the same column in File2 is c4 and so on .. How were you considering to provide that input to the script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: The format of the files i gave is a simple version of the files I'm using, so that you can understand better my question . But for my script I'm using bed format files <chr><start><stop><...><...> with no head included

Comment: What  I was thinking to do is: for each of the fileS add the needed empty columns so that all files have the same number of columns then reorder the colomns with "awk" then use "cat" to  stack them vertically. But i don't know if this is the best way or there is a more efficient way to do it. I'm sorry if the way i asked my question is unappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The following essentially does the task. It essentially builds up a matrix `entry` which is indexed by the row and column names.

```
awk '(FNR==1) { 
        for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { 
           if (!($i in columns)) { column_order[++cn] = $i; columns[$i] }
           c[i+1]=$i
        }
        next
     }
     !($1 in rows) { row_order[++rn] = $1; rows[$1] }
     { for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) entry[$1,c[i]]=$i }
     END { 
        s="";for(j=1;j<=cn;++j) s=s OFS column_order[j]; print s
        for(i=1;i<=rn;++i) {
           row_name=row_order[i]
           s=row_name
           for(j=1;j<=cn;++j) {
              col_name = column_order[j]
              s=s OFS ((row_name,col_name) in entry ? entry[row_name,col_name] : "-")
           }
           print s
        }
     }' file1 file2 file3 file4 ... filen
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @viona if this answered your question, feel free to accept it.

Comment: This answer my question Indirectly, I managed to index each file rows and tested this code and it works. But my originals files have no row index

Comment: @viona so how do you know then that file 3 has row 6 only (see example)

Comment: i'm working with a data base of (4*300 sample) bed file (format for file i for example: <chr><start><stop><name_i ><othername_i> and with no row index. Per sample i have to merge 4 files. what I did to use the code you provided is that I added a column with a unique row indexing per file(example for file i : file_i_row_1, file_i_row2,....)